# What is wrong in this code as it is not giving output picture?

Tags: python, opencv, imshow

The code is not giving the output picture

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('Picture1.jpg',0)
cv.imshow('image',img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.imwrite('Picture1.jpg',img)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Kindly help me the code is not giving the picture in output

Comment: Unclear what you mean by " is not giving the picture in output "

Comment: Actually the code is running but it should give the output black and white image but it is giving no output

Comment: Your code works on my machine. What do you mean when you say "giving no output"? Do you not get a window showing the black and white image or do you get a window but it shows all black? Perhaps all white? Please explain what it is you are getting.

Comment: It is giving me output Process finished with exit code 0 no image no black white screen

Comment: Can you run your script from a Command Prompt if you're on Windows or from a terminal if on a different OS? How are you currently running your script?

Comment: i am doing it on windows

Comment: So run it from a Command Prompt. It might be your IDE that's wonky.

Comment: Check that cv.imread is not flagging an error of some sort, such as "no such file"

Comment: There i no error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `Picture1.jpg` file is in the same directory as the python file you are running.

Or try calling `startWindowThread()`:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('Picture1.jpg',0)
cv.startWindowThread()
cv.imshow('image',img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.imwrite('Picture1.jpg',img)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The directory is same

Comment: And after applying startWindowThread() same result